# JAXB minOccurs=0. Element exists or not?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML schema:

```
<xsd:element name="Person">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
   <xsd:element name="lat" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="lon" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

And I have an XML message:

```
<Person>
 <name>Fred</name>
</Person>
```

I use JAXB to auto-generate my classes (i.e. Person.java, etc).

So at run time I use JAXB to unmarshal the above XML message and get a Person object instance. When I do a `p.getLat()` or `p.getLon()` the return values are 0.0 even though the original XML didn't contain `<lat>` or `<lon>` elements.

What makes this worse is that 0.0, 0.0 is a valid latitude and longitude. It's rare for a person to be located there but that's beside the point!

An [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-modelparsedb1/index.html) on the IBM site suggested using an additional XML element as metadata to explicitly state whether the optional element exists or not. i.e.

```
<xsd:element name="hasLat" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<xsd:element name="hasLon" type="xsd:boolean"/>
```

So the XML message above would become:

```
<Person>
 <name>Fred</name>
 <hasLat>false</hasLat>
 <hasLon>false</hasLon>
</Person>
```

This seems like an ugly hack. There must be a proper way with JAXB to check if the element existed so that I can trust the return value from my `getLat()`, `getLon()`?

Comment: Are you using JAXB from Java 6 or the separate lib working with 1.5? There were changes in how JAXB generates classes along the way. especially for arrays. Try the latest one.

Comment: I'm using JAXME (on Fedora the package is ws-jaxme-0.5.1-3.4.fc11.noarch) and Java 6 (java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-30.b16.fc11.i586).

Comment: This seems to be a problem specifically with the JAXME implementation of JAXB 2.0. Switching to Sun's implementation the getter returns a null value if the element was not included in the XML message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see that problem at all. For me `xjc` generates a `Person` class with the properties `lat` and `lon` with type `Double`.

If I unmarshall an XML file with no `<lat>` or `<lon>` elements, then the resulting `Person` objects has `null` values for those properties, as I'd expect.

I don't know how you get `0.0` anywhere.

My XML Schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/person">
 <xsd:element name="Person">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:element name="lat" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="lon" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

My `Test.java`:

```
import com.example.person.Person;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;
import java.io.File;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("foo.xml"), Person.class);
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    System.out.println(p.getLat());
    System.out.println(p.getLon());
  }
}
```

My `foo.xml`:

```
<Person>
 <name>Fred</name>
 <lat>1.0</lat>
</Person>
```

Output:

```
Fred
1.0
null
```

Comment: I just tried your example and it works as you suggested. This is good news! It's not a limitation of JAXB but a problem with my project. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for getting 0.0 returned vs null is the use of the Double primitive type or Double object type.  The Double primitive will default to 0.0 if the value is null, since null is not a valid value for primitive types.  The Double object will allow you to assign a null value to these fields.  A peak at your Person class will probably reveal this.

Comment: Yes I think you are right about the double vs. Double. However the problem seems to stem from JAXME converting xsd:double to java primitive double and Sun Java JAXB converting a xsd:double to a java Double. The JAXME gererated code provides no way to check if the <lat> <lon> values in the XML were set. Checking for 0.0 is not desirable because 0.0 is a valid value for latitude and longitude. I have switched to using JAXB so that I can check for null to determine if the element was provided.