# How do I assign a boolean value based on the existence of an element in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668121/representing-element-as-boolean-with-jaxb) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957708/how-do-i-specify-the-adapters-which-jaxb-uses-for-marshaling-unmarshaling-data) which I asked yesterday.

I would like to use a boolean to determine whether or not an element exists in an XML document. The files that I am parsing allow for elements such as the following:

```
<FamilyMember>
    <Name>Jeff</Name>
</FamilyMember>
<FamilyMember>
    <Name>Spot</Name>
    <IsPet/>
</FamilyMember>
```

In this example, the element  specifies that the FamilyMember is a pet, but there is no additional data associated with this element.  I would like to be able tell JAXB to return a boolean based on whether or not the  element exists in the parsed file. If the element exists, the value should be true; otherwise, it should be false. I would like to to this from within the XSD schema which I use to generate my Java classes, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with an XmlAdapter similar to the following:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/represent-string-values-as-element.html

Once you have the answer to ( [How do I specify the adapter(s) which JAXB uses for marshaling/unmarshaling data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957708/how-do-i-specify-the-adapters-which-jaxb-uses-for-marshaling-unmarshaling-data)) you will be able to apply the adapter.

---

The following is how it could be done.  Note the following example works using [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), but throws an exception when the JAXB reference implementation is used.

**FamilyMember**

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name="FamilyMember")
public class FamilyMember {

    private boolean pet;
    private String name;

    @XmlElementRef
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IsPetAdapter.class)
    public boolean isPet() {
        return pet;
    }

    public void setPet(boolean pet) {
        this.pet = pet;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**IsPetAdapter**

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import forum204.IsPetAdapter.IsPet;

public class IsPetAdapter extends XmlAdapter<IsPet, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean unmarshal(IsPet v) throws Exception {
        return null != v;
    }

    @Override
    public IsPet marshal(Boolean v) throws Exception {
        if(v) {
            return new IsPet();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name="IsPet")
    public static class IsPet {
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package example;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FamilyMember.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller= jc.createUnmarshaller();
        FamilyMember fm = (FamilyMember) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(fm, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: What would my schema look like in this instance?

Comment: This method also seems difficult to extend...what if I had multiple elements like <HasTail/> and <NeedsShots/> (in addition to <IsPet/>)? Would I have to write a new adapter class for each one, even though essentially I want them to all do the same thing (return true if the element is present, false if not)?

Comment: @Blue - I lead EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy), and I have entered an enhancement request for a feature that would make this use case easier to map (https://bugs.eclipse.org/345969).  Please feel free to add details to the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Does your IsPet manifest as a Boolean? In which I case I'd guess that the Boolean would be null if it's not present in the XML. I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806098/jaxb-minoccurs-0-element-exists-or-not)indicates this is the case.

Comment: That's kind of the point of my question. I can make the IsPet be parsed as a boolean, but if it's not present, it returns null. Rather than check it as null or not, I'd like to set its value to true if it's not null, and false otherwise.